# Continuous bijection of two balls

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be the union of the open unit ball and its bourdary on the first quadrant.

Let $Y$ be the union of the open unit ball and its bourdary on the first and second quadrant.

Does there exists a continuous bijection $f\colon X\to Y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem correctly. If the boundary of the unit ball on the first quadrant includes two endpoints, then the answer is YES.

In the polar coordinates, set $$X_1 := \{(r,\theta):0< r\leq 1, 0\leq \theta\leq \pi/2\} \text{ and } X_2 := \{(r,\theta): 0<r < 1, \pi/2<\theta < 2\pi\};$$
$$Y_1 := \{(r,\theta):0< r\leq 1, 0\leq \theta\leq \pi\} \text{ and } Y_2 := \{(r,\theta): 0<r < 1, \pi<\theta < 2\pi\}.$$

Then $X = X_1 \sqcup X_2 \sqcup \{O\}$ and $Y = Y_1 \sqcup Y_2 \sqcup \{O\},$ where $O$ is the origin. Let $$f(r,\theta):=\begin{cases}(r,2\theta) & \text{if }(r,\theta)\in X_1, \\ \left(r,\frac{2}{3}(\theta+\pi)\right) & \text{if }(r,\theta)\in X_2, \\ (r,\theta) & \text{if }(r,\theta)=O.
\end{cases}$$

It is easy to check that $f$ is a continuous bijection.